# Why do two moving inertial frames of reference atribute the same velocity to each other?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

In both relativity and Newtonian mechanics, it is a self-evident axiom according to which two inertial observers who move relative to each other measure the same velocity of, say, $v$. I want to know why this is so. One may say that our daily experience, easily verifies this postulate, however, to me, it is not convincing.

Assume that two objects $A$ & $B$ are at rest with respect to each other. Then, $B$ decides to approach $A$ at a constant velocity after undergoing an arbitrary acceleration. If $A$ measures the velocity of $B$ as $v_{BA}$, I can easily claim that $B$ measures the velocity of $v_{AB}$ for $A$ so that for non-relativistic velocities we always have:
$$v_{BA} \approx v_{AB}=v$$
However, which experiments have verified the above equation thus far for when the velocities are relativistic?

For better compatibility with experiment, assume that $B$, who has already undergone an acceleration, can never exceed the speed of light as measured by $A$. ($v_{BA}<c$) 
Now, assume that $v_{AB}$ complies with the challenging equation below:
$$v_{AB}=\gamma_{v_{BA}}v_{BA}$$ 
where $\gamma_{v_{BA}}$ is the traditional Lorentz factor. It is clear that if $c/{\sqrt{2}}<v_{BA}<c$, $v_{AB}$ exceeds the speed of light so that for $v_{BA}\approx c$, $v_{AB}$ tends to infinity. If we want to disprove the odd equation above, we have to investigate the viewpoint of observer $B$ for when his velocity is a considerable portion of the speed of light as measured by $A$. According to our current technology, it seems impossible to set a *human being* in motion at a significant portion of the speed of light, and want him/her to *tell* us about their measurements as to the relative velocity of the surrounding objects especially the other observer ($A$)!

Although this deduction upsets the symmetry of special relativity, I am curious to know if there are some experiments against this idea.

Comment: I am not familiar with special relativity. However isn't it true that two inertial observers moving relative to each other measure the same **acceleration and not velocity**.

Comment: I am afraid not!

Comment: Let's say that I move with $1m/s$ and you move at $2m/s$ in the same direction. If we observe a stationary object, you will measure $-2m/s$ and I will measure $-1m/s$ for the same object.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. There is no third object in my example. Assume that I move at $1m/s$ towards you. (Indeed, *you* attribute this velocity to me.) What velocity do *I* measure for you who approach me? This is the question.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to devise new experiments to disprove your formula- the formula is clearly already incompatible with the existing experimental evidence for special relativity.

In any case, your understanding of the experimental requirements is wrong. You do not have to accelerate a human to a speed approaching c in order to test relativistic effects- you just need sufficiently accurate clocks and measuring devices. Modern atomic clocks are capable of measuring time dilation at everyday speeds.

Comment: Modern configurations can only show how time changes for, say, an atomic clock from the viewpoint of the lab observer. It is not clear how the lab time changes from the viewpoint of an atomic clock that has reached a considerable portion of light speed undergoing an acceleration. I still do not understand how accurate clocks and measuring devices or any specific experiment prove that the observation of a fast-moving light clock suggests that the lab clocks *dilate* as well as it does for the moving light clock as viewed in the lab frame.

Comment: You are not thinking of it properly. If velocity was not reciprocal, then either time or distance would have to be non-reciprocal, which disagrees with experimental fact.

Comment: Also, you again mistakenly are fixated about reaching 'a considerable proportion of the speed of light.' It is not necessary to reach a considerable proportion in order to determine the relationship between two quantities.

Comment: To determine the relationship by what? By experiment or by theory? Yes, I agree with you if it is the theory (SRT) that determines this relationship in its *determined* way. However, if it is about experiment, this relation may differ from that determined by SRT. Does really any experiment validate time dilation from both viewpoints of the lab and the moving frames simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being intuitive and also required by the principle of relativity, this is actually fairly easy to derive directly from the Lorentz transform.  For simplicity of notation I will suppress the y and z direction and do a Lorentz transform in matrix form using units where c=1.  So if frame B is moving at velocity v with respect to frame A then the transform from A to B is $$\Lambda(v)= \left(\begin{array}{rr}
{\gamma} & -{\gamma} v \\
-{\gamma} v & {\gamma}
\end{array}\right)$$
where $\gamma=(1-v^2)^{-1/2}$. Now, the transform from B to A is  $\Lambda(u)$ such that $$\Lambda(u)\Lambda(v)= \left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
The solution to this is $\Lambda(u)=\Lambda(v)^{-1}=\Lambda(-v)$. So the velocity of A with respect to B is equal and opposite of the velocity of B with respect to A.

Comment: For God's sake, forget about that Lorentz transformation for a couple of days! I just want to know if an *asymmetric relativity* is **empirically** tenable.

Comment: That is a rather excessive response. The Lorentz transform is empirically verified, so all empirically tenable theories must be empirically equivalent to the Lorentz transform

Comment: Even if the Lorentz transformation is experimentally correct, this does not mean that other possible transformations are not or cannot be empirically verified.

Comment: Besides, there are still some ambiguities with, e.g., the length contraction in SR. I think there is not any performed experiment that has *directly* verified/detected the length contraction.

Comment: “this does not mean that other possible transformations are not or cannot be empirically verified.” It does mean that any such transforms must be empirically equivalent to the Lorentz transform. I.e. they might redefine v, but when you go to measure velocities using e.g. Doppler radar, then you will get u=-v. Also, remember this site is for mainstream physics

Comment: All experiments, on their best form, verify the Lorentz transformation from the viewpoint of only *one* observer. (The observer in the lab frame, that is.) The viewpoint of the (accelerated) observer moving at a considerable fraction of the speed of light is confirmed mathematically (Lorentz transformation) rather than experimentally due to the technology limitations. That is to say, our experiments have *not* really verified the Lorentz transformation from all aspects yet.

Comment: None of that is correct. There is definitely no such restriction. An experiment may be analyzed from any reference frame, not merely the lab frame. For example, GPS uses a reference frame where none of the components of the system is at rest. This is clearly a waste of time, and you have no intention of upvoting or accepting a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Okay. It seems that GPS has verified SR as the ultimate theory of physics with unquestionable postulates! Indeed, you feel as if there is no place for any rational dissidents.